# Would this be a correct integral for volume of this torus?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have a circle centered at (0,2) with a radius of 1 revolving around line x=2. And I need to find the volume of the torus formed from this. Here is the integral that I have managed to set up so far:

$ \int_1^2 2π(2-x)(2)\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}dx\ + 2 $

However, I am not sure if the intervals of the integral are correct, since the radius is one.

I got the y value since my circle equation is x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 1, so you'd just have to solve for y in this case.

Comment: To get the volume, there is no need to compute a complicated integral. you could use [Pappus's centrod theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that you have a circle

$x^2 + (y-2)^2 \leq 1$

As the circle forms for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, your bounds for $x$ is incorrect.

Also for limits of $y$, $ \ 2 - \sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq 2 + \sqrt{1-x^2}$

And that gives height of each shell as $2 \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

As the circle is being rotated around $x = 2$, radial distance of shell from the axis of rotation is $(2-x)$.

So the integral to find volume using shell method is,

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 2 \pi (2-x) \cdot 2 \sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx = 4 \pi \int_{-1}^1 (2-x)  \sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: A nice feature of this integrand is that the term $ \ x \ \sqrt{1-x^2} \ $ is an odd function, so its contribution to the volume is _zero_ and one only needs to integrate $ \ 2 \ \sqrt{1-x^2} \ $ .  (If you recognize what curve that function represents, you can use "geometric integration" and get the result immediately.  I mention this because the volume of a torus turns up frequently as an exam problem, even before trigonometric substitution is covered.)

Comment: @boojum yes I left some of that for OP. More importantly it is easy to see that the centroid of the circle is at distance $2$ from $x=2$. So volume is clearly $\pi \times 2\pi \cdot 2 = 4 \pi^2$ by Pappu's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

yep so what you have is the circle:
$$x^2+(y-2)^2=1$$
rotated about the $y$-axis. Rearranging you have:
$$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}+2$$
just remember to account for above and below the axis. I am not sure where the $5$ and $1$ have come from, I think it should be $[0,1]$

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to add one more detail to my question. The circle also revolves around the line x=2

Answer (score 2):

HINT

It is also the same as the volume obtained  by revolving circle (with Shifing / Reflection)

$$ (x-2)^2+y^2= 1$$

about the y-axis.